# What's the best, easiest, free way to check in Java if a piece of text is spam?

Tags: java, spam-prevention

What's the best, easiest, free way to check in Java if a piece of text is spam?

Comment: In python that would probably be `text != "eggs"` :))

Comment: Please let us know when you get your best, easiest and free solution to this problem :)

Answer (score 6):

It's not easy at all and requires to have some theoretical / mathematical / statistics background. It's called *Bayesian filtering*, it's just one of the methods but works great.

You can have an introduction and some background on wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering), but it is a topic greatly covered over the internet, just search around (here on StackOverflow too I think).

Answer (score 5):

Probably the easiest way is to leverage an existing API for that. Akismet has [bindings for Java](http://sourceforge.net/projects/akismet-java/), and it's what Wordpress uses on its blogs by default. Oh, and it's free, libre, open source software.

Answer (score 3):

You could pipe it through [SpamAssassin](http://spamassassin.org) and see what the return value is.

Here's a wacky idea: send the text as an email to a Gmail account. Then use IMAP to see whether it ended up in the Inbox or the Spam folder.

Comment: +1 because it's a very interesting possible use case for GMail.

Comment: Before using Gmail as a spam filter for an application, it would be prudent to **carefully** read the "terms of service" for Gmail.

Comment: +1 SpamAssassin looks promising... not java, but i may be able to make some use out of it

Answer (score 2):

Akismet makes all that mathematical and logic for you, I think is the best way to avoid spam.

You only need to [ask for you key](https://akismet.com/signup/) related to your website. There's a free (voluntary paid) way.

A normal call through it's [Java API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/akismet-java) would be like this, I use `commentCheck` for that piece of text you're checking.

```
Akismet akismet = new Akismet(AKISMET_KEY, SITE);
    return akismet.commentCheck(
        request.getRemoteAddr(),
        request.getHeader("User-agent"),
        request.getHeader("referer"),
        "", //permalink
        "comment", //comment type
        "", //author
        "", //email
        "",
        commentText, //Text to check
        request.getParameterMap());
```

If this call returns `true`, it's considered spam.

Comment: I know this answer is too late, but... commentCheck method only checks if there's spam, but not if there are bad words, aggresive language, etc., isn't it?